# Save Webpage contents in a text file

Tags: files, text

I have following weblink:

http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/sequenceText.do?structureId=1APS&chainId=A

I wish to save only certain parts of this file in a text file, that is, I want only the sequence portion (with spaces at correct places) and not the heading or any numbers on that page.

Secondly, we can see there are spaces after every tenth character in all lines. I would like to remove only the spaces which occur after every tenth character and save this content in another text file.

Is it possible ? Can any one help in this regard ?

Comment: I suggest to look up `curl` for downloading and `awk` for text processing.

Comment: legeksteyn is right, use curl or wget for downloading the file and use awk for text processing. but can you show your sample output that you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use egrep with -o switch (Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.) For example: echo page.html | egrep -o ".+" | sed s!!! | sed s!! > output.txt